# Selenium2 Build Error in Maven apache-maven-3.0.5

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver

I came across following error in Maven when run the command

```
C:\Users\Man\SelProj>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SelProj 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.735s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Apr 21 15:25:23 EST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/106M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:m
aven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to
http://repo.maven.apache.org refused: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
C:\Users\Man\SelProj>
```

My POM.xml file as follows, I placed the POM file in the folder where I am running the >mvn clean install cmmand

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>SelProj</groupId>
        <artifactId>SelProj</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <dependencies>
        <!-- Selenium2 dependency -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>2.32.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>
```

What could be the reason. I am running this on windows 8 (64 bit)

Comment: Can you access the `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/` via the web browser?

Comment: @Charlee, It gives following message `Browsing for this directory has been disabled.
View this directory's contents on http://search.maven.org instead.` But `http://search.maven.org/#browse` this cab be accessed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had same issue. Try to use just `>mvn install` command without `clean`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can access it via the web browser, I understand that there is no any issue about the internet connection.

There are 2 significant possible root causes as the following: -

#### 1. The proxy

If you are behind the proxy, please add the `proxy` configuration to the `settings.xml` e.g.

```xml
<settings>
  .
  .
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.somewhere.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  .
  .
</settings>
```

Please see [Maven - Guide to using proxies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) for further information.

#### 2. The Anti-Virus / Firewall Issue

`Firewall` and `Anti-virus` **sometimes prevent** `Java` from running properly, or `Windows Firewall` (and various other Firewalls) **actively prevent** `Java.exe` from reaching out to the Internet to "download stuff" which is a key part of Maven. ***You may need to configure the Firewall or Anti-virus to add exceptions to allow such actions***.

Please see [Maven - Maven on Windows](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/windows-prerequisites.html) for further information.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I don't have proxy in my setup. Further I tried after disabling virus guard. But still same error come up. Following is the java and maven version check results

Comment: `C:\Users\Man>java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

C:\Users\Man>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-20 00:51:28+1100)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.7.0_17, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
C:\Users\Man>`

Comment: Now I'm getting different error when running `>mvn clean build`           `[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "build". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-
version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate
-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package`

Comment: continue... `package, pre-integration-test, inte
gration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: If your current question is solved, please update it. If you face another trouble, please ask a new question.